# Extending mail object in a cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfmail

I use the mail() object in cfscript. I want to extend that object so I can overwrite the setTo() method. Here is the cfc code I have written.

```
component extends="com.adobe.coldfusion.mail"
{
  public void function setTo(String recipients) {
    machineName = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress").localhost.getCanonicalHostName();

    if (FindNoCase("devcomputer", machinename) == 0) 
    {
      super.setTo(arguments.recipients);
    }
    else
    {
      super.setTo(this.getFrom());
    }       
  } 
}
```

When this runs however, I get a message saying the setTo() method does not exist at the line calling super.setTo(). Digging further I looked at the super object and it inherits from java.lang.Class, not com.adobe.coldfusion.email.

What is the proper way to extend ColdFusion's mail object so I can override the setTo() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getters/setters in `com.adobe.coldfusion.mail` are actually not functions, but accessors. Accessors are automatically generated by ColdFusion based on the properties in the component. **Properties are inherited, accessors are not!**

The accessors in the mail component do nothing but set/get the value of the property. The equivalent of `super.setTo(arguments.recipients);` thus is `variables.to = arguments.recipients;`. The equivalent of `this.getTo()` is `variables.to` etc.

Note: Using `accessors="true"` with the component that `extends="com.adobe.coldfusion.mail"` does not work with inherited properties either.

Comment: Properties are inherited, accessors are not.. ~_~ seems like a bug doesn't it?

Comment: Depends on the perspective, I guess. It's designed this way for a reason. Well, I would not recommend to use `(cf)property` to begin with, but that's just me.